# alert not generated even when none of the applicants have selected checkbox

Tags: javascript

In a form can create more than 1 applicant, each applicant has a checkbox field. While submission of form it has to check atleast for 1 applicant checbox field has to be selected.code snippet below not working.Could some one help with the script.

```
function  FF_OnBeforeSave() {
for(var i = 1; i < repeat; i++){
var primaryElement = Primary(i);
    console.log("primaryElement.. "+primaryElement);
    var prim = $(primaryElement).val ();
    console.log("prim.. "+prim);
    if(prim !== false ){

    }
    else {
        alert('Please select atleast 1 primary'); 
        $('#btnsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        return false;
    }

}
$('#btnsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: from where is coming the variable `repeat` ? Please, post a minimal code to us be able to reproduce the error, or post the error you are getting on the console. Also, try to remove the space between `.val ();`

Comment: var repeat = fs('.ff-sec-repeat-wrapper');
for(var i = 1; i < repeat; i++){
 var primaryElement = Primary(i);
 console.log("primaryElement.. "+primaryElement);
 var prim = $(primaryElement).prop('checked');
 console.log("prim.. "+prim);
 if(prim !== false ){
 }
 else {
  alert('Please select atleast 1 primary'); 
  $('#btnsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  return false;
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong method of interface with the check box.
http://api.jquery.com/prop/
Try using 
`$(primaryElement).prop("checked");`

Comment: i tried the one below, even this didn't work for me .                          
var repeat = fs('.ff-sec-repeat-wrapper');
for(var i = 1; i < repeat; i++){
 var primaryElement = Primary(i);
 console.log("primaryElement.. "+primaryElement);
 var prim = $(primaryElement).prop('checked');
 console.log("prim.. "+prim);
 if(prim !== false ){
 }
 else {
  alert('Please select atleast 1 primary'); 
  $('#btnsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  return false;
 }
 
}